# Do 'normal' Kotlin and Kotlin for android differ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

In a "normal" module (in Intellij Idea), there is a constructor of `String` type accepting `ByteArray`, `offset` and `length` as parameters, but when I moved my code to the "android" module, I found out that there is no such constructor.

1. Does Kotlin for Android differ from the "normal" one?
2. How do I create a `String` object from an array of bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like You have different runtime.jar, check it please.

Comment: Kotlin uses the java/android String-class and both contain the String(byte[]) constructor, so I think there is something else wrong.

Comment: Compiler indeed maps kotlin.String to java.lang.String for JVM but kotlin.String has only primary constructor ([proof](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/String.kt#L23)). All other in kotlin are function. You can find implementations [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L185)

Comment: Your IDE plugin version and the Kotlin runtime jar and gradle dependencies should have matching version numbers to be consistent and for everything to function.